# Prove the following set relations.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove the following set relations.

```
(A∩B)⊆(A∪B)
```

My teacher show me the answer that:

```
first,   assume x ∈ A∩B.
second,  x ∈ A and x ∈ B.
third,   x ∈ A or x ∈ B.
fourth,  x ∈ A∪B.
```

so my question is how can we get third step from the second step?

Comment: $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ means $x$ belongs to both $A$ and $B$, which implies that "$x$ is in at least one of $A$ and $B$." Does that make sense?

Comment: In case this is the cause of your confusion, note the inclusive "or" is being used here instead of the exclusive "or".

Answer (score 0):

If $C$ and $D$ are both true, then $C$ must be true and $D$ must be true. Hence $C$ or $D$ is true.